# Rate of convergence of a Weyl-Heisenberg (Gabor) frame expansion

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, approximation, signal-processing, wavelets

If $\{g_{m,n}\}$ is a Gabor frame for $L^2(R)$,  with window function $g$, and $f \in L^2(R)$, is there a bound on the approximation error of $f$ using a finite subset of the frame? That is,   is there a result of the form:
\begin{align}
\left\Vert f - \sum_{m=-M}^{M} \sum_{n=-N}^{N} c_{m,n}\; g_{m,n} \right\Vert \le error(N,M),
\end{align} 
with appropriate restrictions on $f$ and $g$?